# Clearing error state of <mat-error> on focus

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I have an Angular Material 10.2 sign-in component which shows an error via `<mat-error>` when authentication fails, similar to [OKTA's Angular Material login example](https://github.com/JanStureNielsen/okta-angular-material-login-example). When the user moves to amend the email or password fields in the sign-in form, the error state should be removed...but I can't find a way to do that without wiping out the current field values, i.e., the user should be able to move a field, or fields, make corrections and resubmit.

Any ideas how to clear the Angular Material `<mat-error>` state without clearing anything else in the sign-in form?

Here's what the OKTA example does:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <h2>Log In</h2>
  <mat-error *ngIf="loginInvalid">
    The username and password were not recognised
  </mat-error>
  <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
    <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="username" required>
    <mat-error>
      Please provide a valid email address
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
    <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" required>
    <mat-error>
      Please provide a valid password
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

and the component:

```
async onSubmit() {
  this.loginInvalid = false;
  this.formSubmitAttempt = false;
  if (this.form.valid) {
    try {
      const username = this.form.get('username').value;
      const password = this.form.get('password').value;
      await this.authService.login(username, password);
    } catch (err) {
      this.loginInvalid = true;
    }
  } else {
    this.formSubmitAttempt = true;
  }
}
```

When login fails, the application notifies the user:

[image]

The login failure message ("The username and password were not recognized") should be removed as soon as the cursor is placed in either the username/email or password fields, similar to what commercial sites like Google do. The problem is I don't know how to reliably detect this state change.

Comment: can you add some code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `loginInvalid` to false via the on-focus event:

```
onFocus(event: any) {
  this.loginInvalid = false;
}
```

triggered with the `(focus)` event from the `<input` fields:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <h2>Log In</h2>
  <mat-error *ngIf="loginError">
    The username and password were not recognised
  </mat-error>
  <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
    <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="username" required (focus)="onFocus($event)">
    <mat-error>
      Please provide a valid email address
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
    <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" required (focus)="onFocus($event)">
    <mat-error>
      Please provide a valid password
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Html page, You are not check any validation for `mat-error` element.

**Username validation:**

```
 <mat-error *ngIf="!username.dirty && username.invalid">
   Please provide a valid email address
 </mat-error>
```

instead of

```
<mat-error>
   Please provide a valid email address
 </mat-error>
```

Note: You need update password validation as like above one.

Comment: Then you can append those condition to your existed conditions like
`*ngIf="loginInvalid && !username.dirty && username.invalid && !password.dirty && password.invalid"`

Comment: On submit, `username` and `password` fields are both valid and dirty...so these alone cannot make the state necessary state change.

Comment: can you try this with your `*ngIf` condition `(!username.dirty || !password.dirty) && (username.invalid || password.invalid)`.